# How to get system time while running Azure Stream Analytics Query

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

In the application, there are set of events that come to event hub and as part of stream analytics, I have set of requirements and one of them is to find out if certain set of records havent arrived at event hub in last x minutes. I have a timestamp inside the message that tells me the effective time of the message, but in order to compute the lag (between the effective time of the message and now()), I need to know the current timestamp when I am running the query.

I tried System.Timestamp, but it gives me the value "1970-01-01T12:01:01.0010000Z"

The Enqueue timestamp for the message is latest like "2018-05-06T00:00:00.1000000Z"... But not sure why System.timestamp does not return me the enqueue time (when I have not used "Timestamp By" Clause).

So, I have 2 questions:

1. How do I get current timestamp of the server when the stream analytics query is getting executed.
2. Why system.timestamp does not return the enqueue timestamp

Query:
SELECT
   System.Timestamp as ts
FROM
    source

Result:
"1970-01-01T12:01:01.0010000Z"

None of the timestamp in the input data is older than 6th May 2018.

Thanks,
Rajneesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Enqueue timestamp for the message is latest like "2018-05-06T00:00:00.1000000Z"... But not sure why System.timestamp does not return me the enqueue time (when I have not used "Timestamp By" Clause).

As [System.Timestamp (Stream Analytics)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/reference/system-timestamp-stream-analytics) states as follows:

> If a TIMESTAMP BY clause is not specified for a given input, arrival time of the event is used as a timestamp. For example Enqueued time of the event will be used in case of Event Hub input.

I just tested this issue and found that if you just test the query under "JOB TOPOLOGY > Query" of Azure Portal, then for the approach not specifying the TIMESTAMP BY clause, the value of System.Timestamp would be `1970-01-01T12:01:01.0010000Z`. While specifying the TIMESTAMP BY clause, the value of System.Timestamp would be column value you specified in the TIMESTAMP BY clause.

Then, I just created a Blob input and Blob outout for my job, then under Overview tab, click Start to run my Stream Analytics job, I could successfully retrieve the correctly value for System.Timestamp.

**Query:**

```html
SELECT birth,name,System.Timestamp as t   
into output
FROM input
```

**TEST:**

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**

> How do I get current timestamp of the server when the stream analytics query is getting executed.

For your requirement, I assume that you could use [JavaScript UDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-javascript-user-defined-functions). I just created a sample UDF as follows:

```
function main(s) {
    return new Date().toISOString();
}
```

**TEST:**

[image]

You could compute the lag within a UDF or leverage the built-in functions [Date and Time Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/reference/date-and-time-functions-azure-stream-analytics).

Comment: Thanks Bruce... This answers the 2nd question... For the first question: Lets say I am not recieving any data and I need to detect that, in which case I would need to know the System TimeStamp (of the Server) and not the Enqueue time (as no messages are there in Event Hub). Is there a way to find the Stream Analytics Server Current Timestamp irrespective of Source data?   System.Timestamp either tells me Enqueue time or some data element (which is a timestamp) value (via Timestamp By clause)... But My requirement is to find out if no messages of a particular type are present for x seconds.

Comment: For your requirement, I did some test. You could follow the updated part in my answer.